# Filtered include on Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have been reading the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include

> Caution
>
> In case of tracking queries, results of Filtered Include may be
> unexpected due to navigation fixup. All relevant entities that have
> been queried for previously and have been stored in the Change Tracker
> will be present in the results of Filtered Include query, even if they
> don't meet the requirements of the filter. Consider using NoTracking
> queries or re-create the DbContext when using Filtered Include in
> those situations.
>
> Note
>
> In case of tracking queries, the navigation on which filtered include
> was applied is considered to be loaded. This means that EF Core will
> not attempt to re-load it's values using explicit loading or lazy
> loading, even though some elements could still be missing.

```
var orders = context.Orders.Where(o => o.Id > 1000).ToList();

// customer entities will have references to all orders where Id > 1000, rather than > 5000
var filtered = context.Customers.Include(c => c.Orders.Where(o => o.Id > 5000)).ToList();
```

It seems to me that **using Include with Tracking queries is error prone**. Because you have to make sure no tracking queries have been used before Filtered Include is used.

Please correct me if it is wrong.

Comment: Closed this as duplicate because the other answer also touches this area. Your question is opinion-based anyway. It's like many other features: use them when knowing what they do.

Comment: This ticket raised the question at the end that is not covered by another ticket.

Comment: Yes, but that's asking for an opinion, which is off-topic on Stack Overflow. It seems quite obvious to me that if you use a query with a filtered Include you do it in a clean context.

Comment: "error prone" is not an opinion, it is a fact. But I want to get more advice from the community.

Comment: It *is* an opinion. I don't think it's error-prone, its behavior is 100% predictable.